# Powershell Invoke-Command resulting in RegEx error

Tags: powershell, release-management, tfs-2015

I'm using Invoke-Command to execute a powershell expression on a remote server. I'm getting a regex error when the command executes. It appears as though powershell uses RegEx internally to parse arguments, but for some reason, it's failing in this scenario.

What's especially confusing is that the variable that appears to cause the parsing error isn't used at all in the Invoke-Command call. My guess is that some kind of variable capture is happening so that variables can be referenced in the remotely executing script (via the "using" scope), and this is failing for my $ArtifactDirectory parameter. I know it's the $ArtifactDirectory param causing the issue only because the value for the "regex expression" in the exception is the value of the $ArtifactDirectory parameter.

Another important note is that I can run the script (with the exact same param values) manually on the exact same machine as TFS is executing it without error. This tells me it's some kind of session option causing the issue that TFS build/deployment agent is setting.

Here is the relevant portion of the powershell script:

```
param(
    [string]    $ArtifactDirectory,
    [string]    $ComputerName
    )

$someFancyCommand = "this does not seem to matter"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock { 
    Invoke-Expression "$using:someFancyCommand"
}
```

And here is how I'm executing it (in this case, via TFS Release Management):

```
MyScript.ps1 -ArtifactDirectory "C:\MSAgent\_work\66f1e4ebb\Cc - (WIP)\CC - My Cool App" -ComputerName "SomeComputer"
```

Here is the full stack trace:

```
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6024146Z [Exception:System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: The regular 
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6024146Z expression pattern {{C:\MSAgent\_work\66f1e4ebb\Cc - (WIP)\CC - My Cool App}} is not valid. ---> 
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6024146Z System.ArgumentException: parsing "{{C:\MSAgent\_work\66f1e4ebb\Cc - (WIP)\CC - My Cool App}}" - 
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6024146Z Unrecognized escape sequence \M.
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6024146Z    at System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexParser.ScanCharEscape()
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6024146Z    at System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexParser.ScanBasicBackslash()
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6024146Z    at System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexParser.ScanRegex()
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6024146Z    at System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexParser.Parse(String re, RegexOptions op)
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6024146Z    at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex..ctor(String pattern, RegexOptions options, TimeSpan matchTimeout, Boolean 
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6024146Z useCache)
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6024146Z    at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex..ctor(String pattern, RegexOptions options)
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6024146Z    at System.Management.Automation.ParserOps.NewRegex(String patternString, RegexOptions options)
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6024146Z    at System.Management.Automation.ParserOps.ReplaceOperator(ExecutionContext context, IScriptExtent errorPosition, 
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6226512Z Object lval, Object rval, Boolean ignoreCase)
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6226512Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6226512Z    at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception 
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6226512Z exception)
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6226512Z    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6226512Z    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6226512Z    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6226512Z    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6226512Z    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6336645Z    at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipeImpl(ScriptBlockClauseToInvoke clauseToInvoke, Boolean 
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6336645Z createLocalScope, Dictionary`2 functionsToDefine, List`1 variablesToDefine, ErrorHandlingBehavior 
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6336645Z errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe, InvocationInfo 
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6336645Z invocationInfo, Object[] args)
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6336645Z    at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeWithPipe>b__8()
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6336645Z    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceBase.RunActionIfNoRunningPipelinesWithThreadCheck(Action action)
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6336645Z    at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipe(Boolean useLocalScope, ErrorHandlingBehavior 
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6336645Z errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe, InvocationInfo 
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6336645Z invocationInfo, Boolean propagateAllExceptionsToTop, List`1 variablesToDefine, Dictionary`2 functionsToDefine, Object[]
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6336645Z  args)
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6336645Z    at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeUsingCmdlet(Cmdlet contextCmdlet, Boolean useLocalScope, 
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6336645Z ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Object[] args)
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6336645Z    at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand.ProcessRecord()
2016-04-25T13:53:28.6336645Z    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()]
```

Comment: I think seeing an example of how you make `$someFancyCommand` with `$ArtifactDirectory`? I imagine the error is different if you actually ran the command you have list above. Also Why `invoke-expression`? Why not just `-Command` ?

Comment: $ArtifactDirectory isn't used *at all* for $someFancyCommand. That $ArtifactDirectory is used elsewhere in the MyScript.ps1 long after the Invoke-Command call. The expression being executed is basically a TopShelf command line to start/stop/install etc a windows service. The expression itself would look like "& 'c:\myapp\host.exe' start". As I mentioned in my post, the command itself doesn't seem to matter - I can replace that with a  simple Write-Host that uses no variables at all and it still fails.

When you say "why not just -Command", what are you referring to?

Comment: If the error is related to `$ArtifactDirectory` then why don't we see it in use (If the error was coming from PowerShell)?  I had assumed they were related and that you were just running some exe so I questioned your use of IEX. `Invoke-Command -Command` would have worked just as well in that case... Again I was trying to figure out the relationship of the variable to your code. I no nothing about TFS so that could just be my ignorance. Is the error coming from TFS Release Management?

Comment: Sorry - I know it's the $ArtifactDirectory variable only because the value in the exception (that long folder path) is the value that's in the $ArtifactDirectory param.

The error is indeed being logged by the TFS agent during release. Interestingly, this does NOT happen if I run it manually. I'll update the question accordingly - it must be something to do with how the MS Agent executes powershell scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up re-writing the entire script, and magically, the error went away. As others have pointed out, trying the simple version of the script above works fine. Indeed, it works fine both manually executed and executed via TFS Release.

In the end, the error seemed related to a file copy operation later down in the script - and yet that file copy operation worked fine *if* the above Invoke-Command call was removed.

So I'm not sure what's going on, but there was some interaction between the execution of the remote command and the subsequent execution of the following script:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDirectory -Recurse -Exclude $exclude | 
    Copy-Item -Destination {
        if ($_.PSIsContainer) {
            Join-Path $ArtifactDirectory $_.Parent.FullName.Substring($sourceDirectory.length)
        } else {
            Join-Path $ArtifactDirectory $_.FullName.Substring($sourceDirectory.length)
        }
    } -Force -Exclude $exclude -Verbose
```

At any rate, I refactored the above script into a module/function and the issue went away entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and it works with normal PowerShell. As you noted in your question this definitely seems to be TFS Release management issue and it's treatment of the input arguments.

**Resolution / Work Around**: Please try by escaping all the special characters in the path `"C:\MSAgent\_work\66f1e4ebb\Cc - (WIP)\CC - My Cool App"`. The escape sequence in PowerShell is character `\`.

For your convenience here is how the path should look like with escape sequence:

```
"C:\\MSAgent\\_work\\66f1e4ebb\\Cc - \(WIP\)\\CC - My Cool App"
```